# How to evaluate $\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{x^{1010}}{(1 + x)^{2022}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> How to evaluate the following integral? $$\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{x^{1010}}{(1 + x)^{2022}} dx$$

---

**Here's my work:**
$$\begin{align}I &= \int_0^\infty \dfrac{x^{1010}}{(1+x)^{2022}} dx  \\&=\int_0^\infty \dfrac{1}{x^{1012}(1 + \frac1x)^{2022}}dx\end{align}$$

Putting $( 1 + \frac1x) = t$
$$\begin{align}\implies I& =\int^1_\infty -\dfrac{1}{(\frac1{1-t})^{1010}(t)^{2022}}dx\\& =\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{(\frac1{1-t})^{1010}(t)^{2022}}dx \\&=\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{(\frac1{1-t})^{1010}\cdot t^{1010} \cdot (t)^{1012}}dx \\&=\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{(\frac t{1-t})^{1010} \cdot (t)^{1012}}dx\\& =\int_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{(\frac 1{1/t-1})^{1010} \cdot (t)^{1012}}dx \\&=\int_1^\infty \dfrac{(1/t-1)^{1010}}{ (t)^{1012}}dx \\&=\int_1^\infty \dfrac{(\frac{1-t}{t})^{1010}}{ t^2\cdot (t)^{1010}}dx \\& = \int_1^\infty\dfrac{1}{t^2} \cdot\left( \dfrac{1-t}{t^2}\right)^{1010} dx \end{align} $$

---

I don't know how to continue from here. I also thought that Integration by parts would work but not sure how to apply here.

Comment: can use Beta function

Comment: Use IBP to get a recursion relation for $\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{a-1}}{(1+x)^b}dx$.

Comment: [Wolfram alpha times out](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integrate+x%5E1010+%2F+%28x%2B1%29%5E2022+with+respect+to+x+from+x%3D0+to+x%3Dinfinity).

Comment: @Anonymous Sorry, I missed this line. But I think it’s not easy to compute directly.

Comment: Also defeats SymPy: ```>>> integrate(x**1010 / (1+x)**2022, (x, 0,oo))
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

Comment: Hmm so why don't you link that question

Comment: I see. You should that add that into question body. Updoot from me.

Comment: The command of Mathematica 13 `Integrate[x^1000/(1 + x)^2022, {x, 0, Infinity}]` produces `1/39119140740844424655721259526211199447661283851662263492170138196730\
9805961755289996305516974381321282387341380009251927888799782466322683\
8770874136825698469573773611555546773792239157154472610302708179627778\
9956084121104467094815208175619774461706139721649941705102708751556216\
3528379304770292691052410982797623781195067880457984820159423447481820\
4750291627388819441314696168037963160281839482877357663611412965569027\
38624504813...
8381247835975013585166393276858486343988138342171520`.

Comment: @Anonymous Because I thought the method was being tested, not the answer (and that 
 the usage of the Beta function could have been out of syllabus). In any case, thanks for the source, +1, and I'll retract the claim.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values of beta function for positive integral arguments can be derived by just using integration by parts.

**Here's a complete proof**

So you would want to reduce the degrees of the numerator and denominator. To do that you should differentiate the numerator and integrate the denominator. This gives you enough clue as to which functions to choose as the integrable and differentiable one while applying by-parts.

So you proceed by induction.

First step:-

set $x^{1010}$ as the differentiable function and $\frac{1}{(x+1)^{2022}}$ as the integrable one

Now apply by-parts

You get :-

$$-\frac{1}{2021}\frac{x^{1010}}{(x+1)^{2021}}\bigg\vert_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{1010}{2021}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1009}}{(x+1)^{2021}}\,dx=\frac{1010}{2021}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1009}}{(x+1)^{2021}}\,dx$$

Now apply induction to prove that after applying by-parts $n$ times you end up with

$$\frac{1010\cdot 1009\cdots (1010-(n-1))}{2021\cdot 2020\cdots (2022-n)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1010-n}}{(x+1)^{2022-n}}\,dx$$

Obviously $n\leq 1010$.

Therefore for $n=1010$ you endup with

$$\frac{1010!}{2021\cdot 2020\cdots 1012}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(x+1)^{1012}}\,dx=\frac{1010!}{2021\cdots 1012\cdot 1011}$$

**Which is our required answer.**

Proof of the induction step:-

As we have shown that the statement is true for $n=1$.

Let it be true for $n=m$

So after applying by-parts $m$ times we endup with :-

$$\frac{1010\cdot 1009\cdots (1010-(m-1))}{2021\cdot 2020\cdots (2022-m)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1010-m}}{(x+1)^{2022-m}}\,dx$$

Applying by-parts one more time we have:-

$$\frac{1010\cdot 1009\cdots (1010-(m-1))}{2021\cdot 2020\cdots (2022-m)}\bigg(-\frac{1}{2022-m-1}\frac{x^{1010-m}}{x^{2022-m-1}}\bigg\vert_{0}^{\infty}+\\\frac{1010-m}{2022-m-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1010-(m+1)}}{x^{2022-(m+1)}}\,dx\bigg)$$

Which is precisely $\displaystyle \frac{1010\cdot 1009\cdots (1010-(m))}{2021\cdot 2020\cdots (2022-(m+1)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{1010-(m+1)}}{(x+1)^{2022-(m+1)}}\,dx$.

Hence our Formula is true.

**This completes the proof**.

Answer (score 5):

We have,
$$\begin{align}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{1010} }{ (1+x)^{2022}}\,dx \\&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac {x^{1011 - 1} }{ (1+x)^{1011 + 1011}}\,dx\tag{1}\\&= B(1011, 1011)\tag{2}\\& = \dfrac{\Gamma(1011)\Gamma(1011)}{\Gamma{(2022)}}\tag{3} \\& = \dfrac{(1010!)^2}{2021!}\tag{4}\end{align}$$

---

***Explanation:***

$(1.)$, $(2.)$
Expressed the given integral in terms of  [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function)
$$B(x,y) = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{t^{x-1}}{(1 + t)^{x+y}} dt$$

$(3.)$ Used [gamma-beta relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Relationship_to_the_gamma_function)
$$B(x,y) = \dfrac{\Gamma(x) \Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$$

$(4.)$ Relation between [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) and [factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial).
$$\Gamma(x+1) = x!$$

Answer (score 3):

I am going to evaluate the integral in general
$$
I(m, n):=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{m}}{(1+x)^{n}} d x
$$
by a reduction formula of $I(m,n)$.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I(m, n)&=-\frac{1}{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} x^{m} d\left(\frac{1}{(1+x)^{n-1}}\right)\\
&=-\frac{1}{n-1}\left[\frac{x^{m}}{(1+x)^{n-1}}\right]_{0}^{\infty}+\frac{m}{n-1} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{m-1}}{(1+x)^{n-1}} d x\\
&=\frac{m}{n-1} I(m-1, n-1)
\end{aligned}
$$

Applying the formula repeatedly by $m$ times yields

$$
I(m, n)=\frac{m}{n-1} \cdot \frac{m-1}{n-2} \cdot \cdots \frac{1}{n-m} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x)^{n-m}} d x=\frac{m !}{(n-1) (n-2) \cdots (n-m) (n-(m+1))}
$$

In particular,

$$
I(1010,2022)=\frac{1010 !}{2021 \cdot 2020 \cdots 1011}=\frac{(1010!)^2}{2021!}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$$1+x=t$$ $$\int_0^\infty\frac{(x)^{1010}}{{(x+1)}^{2022}}dx=\int_1^\infty\frac{(t-1)^{1010}}{t^{2022}}dt=\frac{1010}{2021}\int_1^\infty\frac{(t-1)^{1009}}{t^{2021}}dt=\cdots=\frac{{1010}!}{2021\cdots1011}$$*Integration by parts

Comment: The integration by parts is applied recursively

Comment: The substitution step is anyways redundant. You should mention that it was applied for easier calculation on your part.

Comment: @Anonymous the last step indicates decreasing products like in the pochammer's products

Answer (score 1):

With trigonometric form $$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2p-1}\theta\cos^{2q-1}\theta d\theta=B(p,q)$$ of Beta function:

Let $x=\tan^2\theta$ then
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{x^{1010}}{(x+1)^{2020}}dx=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^{2021}\theta\cos^{2021}\theta d\theta=B(1011,1011)=\frac{(1010!)^2}{2021!}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Another beta function manipulation:

$$\begin{align*}
I &= \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^{1010}}{(1 + x)^{2022}} \, dx \\[1ex]
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{x^{1010}}{(x+1)^{2022}} \, dx \tag{1} \\[1ex]
&= \frac1{2^{2021}} \int_0^1 (1-x)^{1010} x^{-\frac12} \, dx \tag{2} \\[1ex]
&= \frac1{2^{2021}} \operatorname{B}\left(1011,\frac12\right) \tag{3} \\[1ex]
&= \operatorname{B}(1011,1011) \\[1ex]
&= \frac{(1010!)^2}{2021!}
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : split the integral at $x=1$, and substitute $x\mapsto\frac1x$ for $x\in[1,\infty)$
- $(2)$ : substitute $x\mapsto\frac{1-x^2}{1+x^2}$
- $(3)$ : definition of beta function